# Is there integer $n>3$ such that both $n!-1$ and $n!+1$ are prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, twin-primes

Is there integer $n>3$ such that both $n!-1$ and $n!+1$ are prime?

For $n=3$ we know that $5=3!-1$ and $7=3!+1$ are prime.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: none are known, to my knowledge.

Comment: I wondered this a long time ago. The known examples do not reveal a twin prime of this form and considering how large it would have to be, we can conjecture that there is none.

Comment: @MohammadAbry FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n!-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n!%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), I found the fairly related [Is $n! + 1$ often a prime?](/q/853085/602049), and the somewhat related [Is either $n! + 1$ or $n! - 1$ not prime for all $n$?](/q/3809973/602049).

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime)

Comment: A very similar question has been asked at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401841/are-there-infinitely-many-n-such-that-n-1-and-n1-are-prime-numbers), too. The conjecture is that  $n=3$ is the largest $n$ where both $n!+1$ and $n!−1$ are prime. This is supported by the data from OEIS.

Comment: @Peter  researching, at the level of wikipedia, while a good idea for any such question, is included under the OP's responsibilities.  Hence, there is an apparent lack of research, and it entirely lacks of context of any form.